# Apache Ignite - Read All Key, Values using Affinity Key

Tags: java, ignite

I am new to Apache Ignite and I am planning to use ignite for one of my application. But, I am stuck with one use case (may be very basic).

Use Case:
I have two entities
Employee and Organisation. 
Using Collocation, I can store employees belongs to one Oganisation on one Node.
But how do I read all employees belongs to one Orgnisation using the Organisation key?
I don't want to send the query to all the nodes in cluster for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send query to partition owner by using `ignite.compute().affinityCall(any key with this affinity key or partition id)`.

Please note that partitioning data over organization id is not recommended, since it will likely cause uneven data distribution between partitions.

Comment: Thanks @alamar. Now, I understood how to send the compute job to the particular node using affinity call. But is there any way, how to read all entries from one or more partition (s) of that Cluster Node?  I see there is function localSizeLong(partitionId, CachePeekMode) but No function to read all entries using partition id(s).

Comment: You can use a `ScanQuery(<partition id>)` to do that.